# request Method Options not working in CEFsharp

Tags: cefsharp

I have a problem with my simple Windows Forms App. The app is inteded to only fit our "Docuware Web Browser" to Single and Multimonitor Workplaces.
Everything works fine except some xhr requests against a local installed app (Docuware Desktop Apps) which handles printing and mailing of the documents in Browser.
When i send it from Chrome Browser everything is working fine. On my windows Forms app it seems to cut request with type "OPTIONS". (I guess this is what stops functionality)
I have no control over the Javacript code and the webpage code in general.
Here are some Screenshots of Chrome debugger:

1. Chrome Browser
   [Request type Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hW88.png)
   [connection established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0JrG.png)
2. CEF
   [Options missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDi6S.png)

Im no Web Programmer so its just a wild guess, perhaps its a limitation of CEF or the root cause is something else.
Perhaps someone can help me to find the right direction.
this is my initialization of the browser, as u can see i tried to implement Irequesthandler, still with no luck.

> ```
> wbclient = New ChromiumWebBrowser(url) With {
>         .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
>     }
>     wbclient.BrowserSettings.LocalStorage = CefState.Enabled
>     wbclient.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled
>     wbclient.BrowserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled
>     wbclient.BrowserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled
>     wbclient.RequestHandler = New REQhand
>     wbclient.LifeSpanHandler = life
> ```

I hope this is enough information for the first steps.

Thx in advance

Niklas

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using? It's likely `CEF` doesn't support `Options`, similar though not exactly the same comment at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16637

Comment: well look like its the case if u do it programatically, Wondering if this is also the case when the request is made from the website code.

Comment: Based on the face it's not working, it seems likely. You should ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php for clarification.